# Excel VBA to Access database: Decimal number issue

Tags: database, excel, vba, ms-access, updates

I am working on a small Access DB where I add row values as `1.1, 2.1, 3.1` from an Excel file. When I update, this is getting updated as `1.0999999999, 2.0999999999,3.1000000000000001` in the Access DB. If I want the value of `1.1` in Excel, it is not pulling from the Access DB due to decimal number change. I used "Text" as the data type in the Access DB. Is it because of the text data type or what should I choose to make the update as only `1.1, 2.1`, etc.

Comment: Try to manually convert your excel cell content to string before putting it in your database, my thought is that it converts the float to string when storing it, using litteral binary to decimal, which causes problems with floats. That might be the solution

Comment: The problem is that even though you see `1.1` the computer stores `1.0999999999` in tis memory. It is just how floating point numbers work. If you know you only care about one decimal point the easiest thing to do for comparison is multiply both sides by 10 and take the Integer part. My general way of comparing floating point numbers is something like`Abs(a-b)<0.00001` which is the same as `a=b` would be if a and b were integers.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in the database as text?

Comment: I have a front end excel data entry page and update access-db from excel. and also I retrieve data from excel. when I changed the data type from text to integer for that specific column, system throws error. I am new to  access VBA, any help would be much appreciated. thank you!

Comment: If you writing VBA code, then use the data type currency. If you use single or double (floating), then rounding will occur. If you use currency, then no such rounding will occur.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I would use `CDbl`

Comment: @onedaywhen: I don't ever use fixed point decimals. I use floating point decimals. It is much easier to fix the formatting than to fix the math. If you are committed to using fixed point decimals I don't have the knowledge to help you. Sorry.

Comment: @SunKnight0: fair enough, but be aware that your statement, "even though you see 1.1 the computer stores 1.0999999999 in tis[sic] memory" does not apply to Access SQL because `1.1` is a fixed decimal, not floating point. You might have been using fixed point without realizing it :)

Comment: @SunKnight0: "It is much easier to fix the formatting than to fix the math" - interesting turn of phrase! Be aware the `Format` expression exhibits asymmetric rounding away from zero whereas the `Round` expression exhibits banker's rounding e.g. note the different results here: `SELECT DISTINCT ROUND(CDBL(0.225), 2), ROUND(CDBL(0.215), 2), FORMAT(CDBL(0.225), '0.00'), FORMAT(CDBL(0.215), '0.00') FROM AnyPopulatedTable;`

Comment: I am able to add new record to access DB as I wanted (1, 1.1,2,2.1, etc,), when the data type is “Number” and format is “Double”. However if I want to update the existing record with “update SQL” statement, VBA throws error message (Message: Run-time error ‘2147217913(80040e07)’: Data type mismatch in criteria expression). How can we get this correct?

Comment: @onedaywhen: "1.1 is a fixed decimal, not floating point" -  that is not accurate. How data is stored in memory depends on the field definitions. If you `INSERT/UPDATE` 1.1 to a float or double data type it will be stored as a floating point number in memory. As for the formatting, I almost never have to use `Format` for non-dates. You can set the formatting at the forms/reports to fixed decimal while keeping all the numbers as quick and efficient floats/doubles. All the actual math happens with the full precision.

Comment: @SunKnight0:  "If you INSERT/UPDATE 1.1 to a float or double data type it will be stored as a floating point number in memory." - If you `INSERT/UPDATE` `1.1` to a `CURRENCY` / `DATETIME` / `NVARCHAR(3)` / `NCHAR(3)` / `MEMO` / etc type then it will be stored as `CURRENCY` / `DATETIME` / `NVARCHAR(3)` / `NCHAR(3)` / `MEMO` / etc but doesn't change the fact that you started with a `DECIMAL(n,d)` literal value.

Comment: @SunKnight0: @SunKnight0: You misquoted me: the literal value `1.1` is a fixed decimal **in Access SQL**, as is easily proven e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT TypeName(1.1) FROM AnyPopulatedTable;` ...And further note the `DECIMAL` type has a **higher precedence** than double float in **in Access SQL** e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT TypeName(1.1 * CDBL(2.2)) FROM AnyPopulatedTable;` - returns `Decimal` because the double float is coerced to `DECIMAL` in order to operate on the `1.1` literal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved: I did following changed to the table and access SQL query.

I changed the data type to "Number" and Format to "Double". This is working as I expected. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Round ( expression, [decimal_places] )
```

This will make it one decimal place.

```
Round(PassedVar, 1)
```